# Issue while searching data and selecting row in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a tableview with search bar and save button. Works fine while selecting row and if i want to select other row previous row is deselected and selected row is selected. But, while searching through search bar the selected row is selected but previous row is not deselecting. Result in multiple rows selected. Please help how to deselect previous row while searching through search bar. Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
extension EmpTableView: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if searching {
            return searchedText.count
        } else {
            return empList?.count  ?? 0
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomoCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        var str = ""
        if searching {
            cell.lblTitle.text = searchedText[row].emp_name
            str = searchedText[row].emp_name ?? ""
        }else {
            cell.lblTitle.text = mempList?[row].emp_name
            str = makeList?[row].emp_name ?? ""
        }
        
        if (constants.config.selectedArray.count > 0) && (selectedIndex == row){
            cell.imageSelection.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Selected")
        }else{
            cell.imageSelection.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Unselected")
        }
        var str1 = ""
        if (constants.config.selectedArray.count > 0){
            str1 = constants.config.selectedArray[0]
        }
        
        if str == str1{
            cell.imageSelection.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Selected")
            
        }else{
            cell.imageSelection.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Unselected")
        }
        
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
}

extension EmpTableView: UITableViewDelegate {
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let row = indexPath.row
        
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)  as? CustomCell
        
        if cell?.isSelected == true{
            cell?.imageSelection.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Unselected")
        }else{
            cell?.imageSelection.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Selected")
        }
        
        
        if (constants.config.selectedArray.count > 0) && (selectedIndex != row){
            
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: selectedIndex, section: 0)) as? CustomCell
            
            if cell != nil{
                cell?.imageSelection.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Unselected")
                constants.config.selectedArray.removeAll()
            }
        
        }
        
        if cell?.imageSelection.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Selected") {
            
            if searching {
                constants.config.selectedArray.removeAll()
                let selectedRow = searchedText[row].emp_name
                let selectedId = searchedText[row].emp_id
                constants.config.selectedArray.append(selectedRow ?? "")
                constants.config.selectedArray.append(selectedId ?? "")
                selectedIndex = row
                
            }else{
                constants.config.selectedArray.removeAll()
                let selectedRow = makeList[row].emp_name
                let selectedId = makeList[row].emp_id
                constants.config.selectedArray.append(selectedRow ?? "")
                constants.config.selectedArray.append(selectedId ?? "")
                selectedIndex = row
            }
        }else{
            constants.config.selectedArray.removeAll()
            selectedIndex = -1
        }
        
        self.searchBar.searchTextField.endEditing(true)
        
    }

}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            searching = false
            searchedText.removeAll()
        } else {
            searching = true
            searchedText = makeList.filter{$0.emp_name?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
        }
        empTable.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = ""
    }
```

Comment: Cells are **reused** ... you need to track the "selected" state with your data source, not with `cell?.isSelected`

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There are various ways to approach this, but it's not clear exactly what you're doing... You say *"while searching through search bar the selected row is selected but previous row is not deselecting"* -- when the user types in the search bar, are you filtering your data and calling `tableView.reloadData()`? Is that not clearing the current selection from the table view?

Comment: yes am filtering the data, updated the code, please check. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like you are clearing your `constants.config.selectedArray` when you filter your data?